# How can i query item from list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i wrote this basic code. My goal is writing basic login system. I created two list: kullanici and sifre. Now, i want to compare items in kullanici and username entered by the user. I hope you understand, thx.

```
kullanici=[]  
sifre=[]      

def girisekran():
print("Giriş sistemine hoşgeldiniz")
print("Giriş yapmak için '1' tuşunu, kayıt olmak için '2' tuşuna basın")
x= input()


print("Giriş sistemine hoşgeldiniz")
print("Giriş yapmak için '1' tuşunu, kayıt olmak için '2' tuşuna basın")
x= input()

if (x== "1"):
    print("Kullanıcı Adı: ")  #username
    y= input()

    print("Şifre: ")          #password
    z= input()


if (x== "2"):
    print("Kaydolmak istediğiniz kullanıcı adı: ")  
    k_adi= input()
    kullanici.append(k_adi)

    print("Kaydolmak istediğiniz şifre: ")
    s_adi= input()
    sifre.append(s_adi)

    print("Ana menüye yönlendiriliyorsunuz, lütfen bekleyiniz.")

girisekran()
```

Comment: And what is the language?

Comment: your indentation is broken, please fix your code and edit it so it is clear what belongs where. suggested indentation-depth is 4 spaces per level (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)

Comment: @BlackThunder It looks like Turkish.

Comment: "Kaydolmak istediğiniz kullanıcı adı:" ==>
"The username you want to sign up for:"  - google translate - far more interesting would be why a user from simbabwe produces turkish code :) gotte be a nice story behind that

Comment: It would make it easier for people to help you if you add some comments in English to your code, explaining what each section is supposed to do. Why do you repeat the first 3 lines of your function?

Comment: What do you want to do if 2 or more users have the same name?

Comment: @PM2Ring Actually, you're right. I didn' think 2 or more users have the same name. Bad algorithm pff

Comment: @PM2Ring I defined girisekran() for like login page. When i try call girisekran() func. i gave x is not defined error. So i repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
kullanici=[]
sifre=[]      

def girisekran():
    print("\nWelcome to the entry system")
    print("Press '1' to login, press '2' to register")
    x= input()

    if (x== "1"):
        print("Username: ")  #username
        y= input()
        if y in kullanici:
            print("Password: ")          #password
            z= input()
        else:
            print("\nUsername does not exist.")
            print("Redirecting to Main Menu")
            girisekran()

    if (x== "2"):
        print("Enter username to register: ")  
        k_adi= input()
        if k_adi in kullanici:
            print("Username already exists.")
            print("\nRedirecting to Main Menu")
            girisekran()
        else:
            kullanici.append(k_adi)

        print("Enter the password you want to register")
        s_adi= input()
        sifre.append(s_adi)

    print("\nRedirecting to Main Menu")
    girisekran()

girisekran()
```

This will get you started, but if you want to check if the User's password matches their Name you are going to have to use a Dictionary, I can show you that but not sure if you are that far yet

Comment: Thanks, this is answer i want. You're boss.

Comment: @OllieMcFly You're welcome! was fun using google translate hehe, appreciate if you would click accept answer! cheers :)

Comment: Actually, I thought you are Turkish for a moment Finally, I did it. Now, I'm learning dictionary! Cheers =)

Comment: @OllieMcFly   dictionary are my fav! :) best of luck!